# Using decimal in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I have a column `Amount` defined in my SQL Server database as `varchar(20), null`.

It has values like this:

```
1.56867
2.0
2.0000
2
```

If the user in the client app enters 2 for search, then I need to pull all records from the db except value 1.56867.

So search results should yield:

```
2.0
2.0000
2
```

I tried using this in my SQL query but it's still returning value 1.56867.

```
CONVERT(decimal, myTable.Amout) = CONVERT(decimal, 2)
```

Can you advise?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I can advise. Don't store numbers as strings in your database. Don't even consider to muddle through with converting your strings to numbers in your query. Fix your data model.

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider fixing your data model, and store numbers as numbers rather than strings.

That said, you need to specify a scale and a precision for the `decimal`, otherwise i defaults to `decimal(38, 0)` , which results in the decimal part being truncated. Something like:

```
convert(decimal(20, 5), myTable.Amout) = 2
```

This gives you 20 digits max, including 5 decimal digits. There is no need to explictly convert the right operand here (that's a literal number already).

If your column may contain values that are not convertible to numbers, you can use `try_convert()` instead of `convert()` to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when converting the string `'1.56867'` to `decimal`, SQL server assumes you want 0 decimal places (as pointed out by @GMB), and rounds the value to the nearest integer (2).

```sql
select convert(decimal,'1.56867');

-------
2
```

Also, since your column is defined to hold character data, you should use the `try_cast()` function to avoid `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.` errors that would otherwise occur if non-numeric data is present in the column.

```sql
select *
from (values
     ('1.56867')
    ,('2.0')
    ,('2.0000')
    ,('2')
    ,(null)
    ,('non-numeric value')
     ) myTable(Amount)
where try_cast(Amount as decimal(38,19)) = 2
;


Amount
-----------------
2.0
2.0000
2

(3 rows affected)
```